# How to make tkintertable Table resizable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a GUI using pythons Tkinter (I am using python 2.7 if it makes a difference). I wanted to add a table and so am using the tkintertable package as well. My code for the table is:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from tkintertable.Tables import TableCanvas
class createTable(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.F = tk.Frame(self)
        self.F.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets()
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.table = TableCanvas(self.F,rows=30,cols=30)
        self.table.createTableFrame()
app = createTable() 
app.master.title('Sample Table') 
app.mainloop()
```

I would like to make the number of rows and columns seen change when I  resize the frame. Currently there are 13 rows and 4 columns showing. I would like more to be seen when I make the window bigger. Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated! 
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want to do, not much is needed.

The keyword here is `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure`.
By default, grid rows to not expand after creation when the window size is changed. Using `tk.Frame().grid_rowconfigure(row_id, weight=1)` this behavior changes.

The second thing you missed was that your `createTable` class (please consider renaming it as it sounds like a function) is not set sticky.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from tkintertable.Tables import TableCanvas
class createTable(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #########################################
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.grid(sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)
        #########################################
        self.F = tk.Frame(self)
        self.F.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.table = TableCanvas(self.F,rows=30,cols=30)
        self.table.createTableFrame()

app = createTable() 
app.master.title('Sample Table') 
app.mainloop()
```

should do the trick for you.